# Focus a FormControl if md-error is raised

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Sometimes we are creating form that has many input controls which enable the container *(e.g. div)* to show a vertical scrollbar.

I define this form as a `FormGroup` and every input is a `FormControl` which has an `md-error` template incorporated.

It is possible **to scroll and focus** the form control if its md-error is triggered when submitting the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a Directive for the same and place it on top the Form Control .

```
import { ElementRef, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ 
    selector: '[scrollToError]'
})

export class ScrollDirective {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

  @HostBinding('hidden') isError:boolean = false; 

  @Input() set scrollToError(cond) {
      this.isError = cond; 
      if(cond) { 
          this.elRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
          this.elRef.nativeElement.focus(); 
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi! im trying to use it like this on my control `<input scrollToError type="text" mdInput placeholder="Check number" formControlName="number"> <md-error *ngIf="c.controls['number'].hasError('required')"> This field is <strong>required</strong> </md-error>` still not working

Comment: you need to pass the error to the scrollTo as i am using input there and default is set to false